# Perl : Global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

```
&verify_se_linecount ( \@rows );

### Drop the modified file
open ( OUT, "> $RESOLVED_DIR\\$filenameonly" );

# Loop through each row in the EDI file
foreach my $row  ( @rows ) {
    print OUT $row . "$ROW_DELIM";  #  Line 164
}

close OUT;
```

I have a Perl script (the code above is part of it) that works perfectly on a test server but shows a compilation error on a production server. The error is

```
Global symbol `$ROW_DELIM` requires explicit package name at <script_name> line 164
```

The variable is declared with `our $ROW_DELIM` in a package which is imported in this script. It does not show any error for other objects used from that package.

Comment: You haven't give `$ROW_DELIM"` a value anywhere in that code. You need to address the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Adding `use diagnostics;` will probably help you.

Comment: our $ROW_DELIM;

this is the declaration of varidable in Package

Comment: Voting to close based on OPs comment-in-answer: `Never mind.. i got it. Silly mistake, libraries did not have the updated .pm file. `

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to see how you export/import the function - it'll be one of these things:

- You've declared it with `my` in your package.
- You aren't exporting it like you think
- You aren't importing it like you think.

Try `$OtherPackageName::ROW_DELIM` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't enough to declare the variable in a module that your main code uses: you have to *export* it from that module to make it visible elsewhere

If you need any further help then you must show the contents of the module, together with the statement that imports it into the main code